# Add 2 tags on link in cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp

I am new in cakephp and i have to create a link with 2 tags like following html

```
 <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-th-list"></i> <span>Shop</span></a></li>
```

And in cake php i did something like this:

```
     <li><?php echo $this->Html->link(
      // $this->Html->tag('i', array('class' => array('fa', 'fa-th-list'))),
         $this->Html->tag('span', 'Video / Imagini', null),
           array(
            'controller' => 'users',
            'action' => 'video',
           ),
         array('escape' => FALSE)) ?></li>
```

How can i add the  tag?
I search to internet and on cake book but no details about the second tag.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: You can always bypass Cake's format and just put it in manually: `$this->Html->link('<i class="fa fa-th-list"></i> <span>Shop</span>', array(...), array('escape' => false))`

Comment: Yes, that's an idea, and is good, but i mean if is something more "automatically". After all that's why we add all the code and not do jest HTML

Comment: Yeah fair enough, so what doesn't work about what you've tried? What HTML **is** it outputting?

Comment: Is working, also working using HTML, but i wanted to do it cakephp way. But it was also a good advice, thank you scrowler

Answer (score 3):

Your code was almost correct. I made only some little changes:

```
<li><?php
    echo $this->Html->link(
        $this->Html->tag('i', '', array('class' => array('fa', 'fa-th-list'))) .
        $this->Html->tag('span', 'Video / Imagini'),
        array(
            'controller' => 'users',
            'action' => 'video',
        ),
        array('escape' => false)
    );
?></li>
```